# What is the limit of this formula $ \lim_{x\to \infty} (\arctan x -\pi/2)x$?

Tags: limits

Can you give me full description of the solution?

$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\arctan x -\pi/2)x$

Comment: Hint: x = 1/(1/x)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wW7vSuGCDOU look hear the behaviour of artan near infinity

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\arctan x -\pi/2)x$$

$$= \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(\arctan x - \pi/2)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

This is the indeterminate form $0/0$. Therefore, we can apply l'Hopital's rule.

$$= \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$$

$$= -\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} $$

$$= -\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2}{x^2(\frac{1}{x^2}+1)} $$

$$= -\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2}+1} $$

$$= - \frac{\lim_{x\to \infty}1}{\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{1}{x^2}+1)} $$

$$= -\frac{1}{1}$$

$$= -1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\arctan x-\dfrac\pi2=u\implies x=\tan\left(u+\dfrac\pi2\right)=-\cot u$

Now use $\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{\sin u}u=1$

Comment: How do we move from this point $$ x=-\cot u $$  to this $$ \lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{\sin u}u=1 $$

Comment: @KirillNedelev, $$ (\arctan x -\pi/2)x=-u\cot u=-\cos u\cdot\dfrac u{\sin u}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

Note that $\tan (\arctan x ) = x$ hence we are looking at
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \tan (\arctan x ) (\arctan x - {\pi \over 2})$.

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan x = {\pi \over 2}$ we can replace this by
$\lim_{y \uparrow {\pi \over 2}} (\tan y) (y-{\pi \over 2})$.

Using the substitution $y-{\pi \over 2} = h$ we obtain
$\lim_{h \uparrow 0} -h {\cos h \over \sin h}$ which is straightforward to evaluate using the fact that $\lim_{h \uparrow 0}  {h\over \sin h} = 1$.

Hence $\lim_{x \to \infty} x (\arctan x - {\pi \over 2}) = -1$.

Comment: @Harry: Thanks, I missed that entirely....

Comment: @Harry: I have changed my answer to use a different trick.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>0$,
$$
\arctan x+\arctan\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
Thus the limit is (with the substitution $x=1/t$)
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}-x\arctan\frac{1}{x}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}-\frac{\arctan t}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}-\frac{t+o(t)}{t}
$$